# Mercurial IIS 7.5 Error 500 on bigger push

Tags: iis, iis-7, mercurial

I have set up a Mercurial server on IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 pro following this  tutorial

http://stackingcode.com/blog/2011/02/24/running-a-mercurial-server-on-iis-7-5-windows-server-2008-r2

In contrast to the tuturial I use Windwos 7 Pro, Python 2.7 and Mercurial 3.5 and installed a real (not self signed) certificate and got everything up and running with https after applying the helpful answer of roengraft that can be found here (before it always stopped after pushing about 60MB).

[IIS 7.5 Mercurial setup ignoring maxAllowedContentLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365483/iis-7-5-mercurial-setup-ignoring-maxallowedcontentlength)

BUT: Unfortunately I can only push a bit more than 100MB, I am not able to push a bigger changeset having about 350MB. I always receive Error 500 from the Server. I set all the limits of IIS to max to no avail, they changed nothing. Also all disks have enough space, I tried allowing "Everyone" full access to the repositiories, also to no avail. Now I cannot even checkin anymore and get "502 Bad Gateway" and "500" errors.

Does it make sense to go with linux (its a VM anyway) that hopefully should work better or is there anybody out there (outside the wall) who can help me solving this problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Micha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like always, shortly after posting the question I find the answer on my own. After I have changed the Python command line to this

C:\Python27\python.exe -u -O -B "%s" "%s"

Not exactly knowing what this does in particular, I am happy as it works like a charm now!

After about transferring 120MB it stopped for quite a while but then did the rest in one go. Perhaps this is due to quite some binaries I have to check in as I don't compile them.

Michael