# Why does IIS return code 404.13 instead of code 413 when a request is too large?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

IIS has a configurable threshold for filtering out requests that are "too large" and so could potentially DoS the server. [Such requests yield code 404.13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9310926/57428). Yet HTTP has code 413 `Request Entity Too Large` that looks like it is exactly for such cases.

Why is code 404 returned instead of code 413?

Answer (score 3):

I can't say *why* IIS decided to avoid an official code for "Request Entity Too Large" and go with their own version. [IIS 7 (where 404.13 was introduced, also see here for more status codes)](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/943891) certainly pre-dates [RFC 2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068) definition of 413. Interestingly, [IIS 5 and 6 used the official 413 code](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/318380). If anything, it would probably have made more sense to subclass 413 under 403 (Forbidden).

[This IIS 7 Q&A](http://forums.iis.net/t/1151762.aspx?iis7%20change%20http%20status%20404%20Not%20Found%20to%20413%20Request%20Entity%20Too%20Large%20) suggests that you can write your own HttpModule to convert 404.13 response to a 413 response.

Side note: according to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), 413 is now called "Payload Too Large"