# Can I find whether maximum POST size was too large?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I send a file via POST to my ApiController.

If the file is below 2 MB, everything works like a charm.
If the file is bigger, I get a Error 404.

This is the (old) function declaration in my Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage FileUpload(HttpRequestMessage req, string entryId = "", string owner = "", int debug = 0)
 {
```

which returns, if the entity is too large, this:

```
Remote Address:172.17.41.12:443
Request URL:https://webdevserver/myapp/api/Debug/FileUpload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

or if it is inside the size limits, this:

```
Remote Address:172.17.41.12:443
Request URL:https://webdevserver/myapp/api/Debug/FileUpload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

So I want to send a useful error message - which Error 404 definitely is NOT! - and stumbled upon HTTP Status Code 413, which IIS doesn't send automatically :( so I changed my code to:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage FileUpload(HttpRequestMessage req=null, string entryId = "", string owner = "", int debug = 0)
{
    if(req==null) {
        // POST was not handed over to my function by IIS
        // now is it possible to check whether file was empty or too large!? Because
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge);
        // should only be sent if POST content was really too large!
```

So, how can I check whether the size of the POST data was too big or POST was empty?

Comment: Please check this article [webrequest-failing-with-a-404-13]([http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310926/iis7-webrequest-failing-with-a-404-13-when-the-size-of-the-request-params-exce)

Comment: @bastos.sergio Thanks for your feedback. That question is asking how to increase the size. I think it is unnecessary to increase the size any further than I already did. I only would like to find out whether the error has happened, to throw a 413 instead of a 404, but I don't know how (if at all) I could find out that it really happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [blog](http://blogs.msmvps.com/bernard/2006/12/18/what-s-changed-iis-7-status-codes/), the status code `404.13` was introduced in IIS 7 to replace the http status code `413`.

Since this was done by design, I would suggest that you maintain the response as is, and in your code try to determine whether the 404 error was actually a 404.13 error.