# HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found, when uploading big file in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, web-config

I want my web application to upload big zip file on the server. Here's my code logique :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddApplication", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <span>PUT FILE HERE : <input style="min-width: 550px;" type="file" name="zippedApp" /></span>
    </div>
}
```

In back hand c# code :

```
  [HttpPost]

  public ActionResult AddApplication( string description, HttpPostedFileBase zippedApp)
  {
     //code
  }
```

The C# function is not reached... before it even enters the function i have :

> HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found

So i read this :

[IIS7 - Webrequest failing with a 404.13 when the size of the request params exceeds 30mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310926/iis7-webrequest-failing-with-a-404-13-when-the-size-of-the-request-params-exce)

And it makes me feel like no one really knows the answer. Because in my case i'm sure it is related to MVC web.Config.

I added a bunch of `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="6000" />` in every pieces of config i could find... but no succes yet.

Comment: You'll likely have to make some changes to IIS itself. Refer to this article for more details depending on your IIS version: http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm. The reason it doesn't reach your method is because IIS already filters your request out before the controller is even reached (remember that the request goes through IIS in order to reach your application). Ensure that the filters allow more than the default limit.

Comment: Told you in my question IIS is perfect, other apps are able to do the same

Comment: Try setting the maxAllowedContentLength attribute. <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="102400000"/>

The hierarchy is: system.webServer -> security -> requestFiltering -> requestLimits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will also need to add this for IIS7+

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> <!--50MB-->
     </requestFiltering>
    </security>   
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hu ! it's working... that's the quickest answer i ever had thanks... it say i can only accept answer at least 15 minutes after posting question

Comment: This solved it for me.  It either wasn't stated, or I overlooked the fact that the default will apply in this section whether you like it or not!